# Make it a person to person, please

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Make it a person to person, please.

What does this sentence mean? In what context, the sentence above could be used?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: In an English book.

Comment: You need to tell us _what_ book you read it in and what the context was.

Comment: There was no context: only one short sentence was presented

Comment: OK, but _in which book_?

Comment: Just a book for TOEFL preparation

Comment: You might consider another book.  That sentence has no context to make it meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

On its own, it doesn't make sense.

The phrase *person to person* (or *person-to-person*) can be used adjectivally or adverbially, and so we could say

> A person-to-person call.

or

> I want to speak to him person to person.

You could therefore say of a call

> Make it person to person.

But your original sentence *Make it a person to person* is like saying *Make it a big* or *Make it a happy*: I would say these are not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The senternce has been said to talk about a call. The full form is:

Make it a person-to-person call, please.

person-to-person means "taking place directly between individuals".

If I call you and only the two of us talk to each other over the phone (which is normally the case with phone calls), it will be a person-to-person call.

Comment: Could be a meeting (i.e. not Zoom etc).